# Error Establishing DB connection WordPress (AWS Linux2, MariaDB, Apache)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, mariadb

So I am trying to set up a simple WP page on my AWS EC2 instance. I have one instance which has Wordpress, Apache and php. I have another instance which has a Maria DB set up.

Here is the configs for each instance

**DB Instance**

server.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/mnt/disk-1/db-data/mysql/
socket=/mnt/disk-1/db-data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

client.cnf

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/mnt/disk-1/db-data/mysql/mysql.sock
```

MariaDB repo

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Maria DB is mounted correctly

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@datadir;
+----------------------------+
| @@datadir                  |
+----------------------------+
| /mnt/disk-1/db-data/mysql/ |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I launched MariaDB, I created a db and a user. Gave the user all privileges on the database and set it to user@private-ip-of-webserver and it identified by the password of the user

**Web Server Instance**

created external volume and mounted apache onto it

```
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/disk-1/www"
    #
    # Relax access to content within /var/www.
    #
    <Directory "/mnt/disk-1/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Further relax access to the default document root:
    <Directory "/mnt/disk-1/www">

    . . .
```

Installed PHP 7.2

Installed WP

```
 // ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
 /** The name of the database for WordPress */
 define('DB_NAME', 'wpdb');

 /** MySQL database username */
 define('DB_USER', 'user');

 /** MySQL database password */
 define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
 /** MySQL hostname */
 define('DB_HOST', 'put-the-private-ip-of-db-instance-here');
```

Started up MariaDB.

Started up apache

When I go to my webservers public IP /wp-admin I get the following message "Error establishing a database connection"

I am not sure what I should check to locate the issue. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you replace the second column in those Defines??

Comment: @RickJames Yep the defines were set up correctly. The issue ended up being my inbound rules on AWS. Once I set them up so that they would allow all traffic, the issue was sorted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was to do with my inbound rules on the security groups used by the instances. FYI for anyone who comes across this. For testing purposes, just allow all inbound traffic. :)